# Kafka does not reconsume messages after group-id has changed and offset.reset is set to earliest

Tags: apache-kafka, alpakka

I am trying to test a feature that requires reconsuming the kafka messages from an earlier offset. I changed the group id into a new one and the auto.offset.reset = "earliest", but that didn't solve the problem at all.
On top of this I tried

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server etc.etc.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 --group etc --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute

and I get

> Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=FIND_COORDINATOR).

My third attempt was to simply set up in my application code where I instantiate the consumer the following subscription:

```
    val subscription = Subscriptions.assignmentWithOffset(new TopicPartition(kafkaConfig.topic, partition), 0)
```

And... it still does not work.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: On Confluent Cloud, you'll need to provide authentication details with `--command-config` for any cli scripts to work, but changing the consumer group should work too

Comment: Perhaps a connectivity issue. Did you check listing the topics or running kafka-console-consumer with the same bootstrap servers?